# Highchart automatically add quotes to the variable

Tags: php, charts, highcharts

I use hightchartPHP to display chart. But being a bug, hope people take the time to read and help me.

```
$chart->series[] = array(
'name'      =>  'Sales',
'data'      =>  array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

Code run.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But, i get data mysql

```
$chart->series[] = array(
'name'      =>  'Sales',
'data'      =>  array($sales->monthly_sales()));
```

then automatic highchart add quote . Code not run.

```
["1,2,3,4,5,6"].
```

I tried by add json_encode. But code not run.

```
["\"1,2,3,4,5,6\""]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JSON.parse before you send data (string) into a series data.

```
series : [{          
   data: JSON.parse(data)
}]
```

Because you get string with php not a javascript array of numbers! another easy and not good approach is to remove quotes from your php string `$sales->monthly_sales()` with something like this:

```
str_replace('"', "", $string);
```

Comment: sorry, i use php not javascript. i complate because use array_map. Thank you. i transfome string to int.